# Android mDNS TXT record

Tags: android, mdns

I am trying to access the mDNS TXT record in an android App using "Network Service Discovery" APIs. Basically my app needs to discover the services and access the TXT record from them.

How to access the mDNS TXT record from the android Network Service Discovery APIs. Is support there to access the TXT record from the Network Service Discovery APIs.

Answer (score 3):

Support for accessing TXT records was only just added in API Level 21 (Android 5.0) via the [getAttributes() method on NsdServiceInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdServiceInfo.html#getAttributes()).

If you need to support older Android versions you unfortunately need to use a library like [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net) to get access to TXT records.

Comment: GetAttributes() is still not working on API 21: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35810

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned in comments the [NsdServiceInfo.getAttributes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdServiceInfo.html#getAttributes()) method is to access the TXT record but [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35810) means that the getAttributes() result is empty. This makes the Network Services Discovery API useless if you need the TXT record.

I wish Google would fix this, since using NsdManager compared to e.g. [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) seems to be much faster at finding services. In the meantime, if it helps I have developed a workaround to manually fetch the TXT record over the wire when NsdManager notifies of a new service. This has been [open sourced as a library](https://github.com/youviewtv/tinydnssd) under the MIT License.

Answer (score 0):

My collegae found a great library to bypass this bug which uses the real Apple DNSSD Java API:

[RxDNSSD](https://github.com/andriydruk/RxDNSSD)

[BonjourBrowser](https://github.com/andriydruk/BonjourBrowser) is a great sample app which uses all the features on Android. It is also great for creating your own mDNS service for testing purposes.

I tried TinyDNSSD mentioned below by Steve Lilly but that was not usable for me because it does not work when your service does not have all the records. When f.e. an A-Record is missing it does not work (TimeOutException).